# React Axios Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm using **axios-hooks** in my **react** project. I have a problem that whenever I re-render the component, the backend is called and at the beginning, the same endpoint is called twice.
I'm using it in a following way:

```
import useMyHook from '../../hooks/useMyHook ';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { getData } = useMyHook (category);
  ...
  <Button onClick={getData}...
}
```

**getData is called to refresh the data (so it's normal that the backend is called again here)

```
export default function useMyHook(category) {
  const { language, contextData,  dispatch } = useAppContext();
  const config = {... url, headers, params ...};
  const opts = { manual: false };

  const [{ data: myData, loading, error }, reFetch] = useAxios(config, opts);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (_.isEmpty(contextData) && !_.isEmpty(myData)) {
      dispatch({ type: DATA_LOADED, payload: myData});
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [myData]);

  const getData = () => {
    dispatch({ type: DATA_RESET});
    reFetch();
  };

  return { loading, error, getData};
}
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation?
PS. I've seen that `useAxios` has

```
useAxios(){...}, [stringifiedConfig]) and stringifiedConfig=JSON.stringify(config)
```

and in my understanding, it shouldn't re-call the backend  if the config doesn't change.

Comment: What does BE mean?

Comment: @SuleymanSah BackEnd

Comment: @FarukT  thank you, I will edit the question:)

Comment: your `useAxios` hook is not "guarded". Every time react re-renders `MyComponent`, your custom hook `useMyHook` is called. Then inside that hook you always do an axios call. You'd need to define conditions on when to call the `useAxios` hook and when not. You should use a `useEffect` hook with the deps for that.

Comment: It seems that it is "guarded" inside the axios-hooks library. There is a useEffect and inside we have the call to the backend when [stringifiedConfig] updates: https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the problem is because of state dispatching.
Whenever we change the state, the component that is calling axios-hooks is unmounted and mounted again so we do a second call.

The workaround is to check if the value is not undefined inside useEffect of the component and then call the axios-hook and disable the automatic call {manual: true} in useAxios.